# jQuery populate div from select option - IE7 issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to populate a div with the value of an `<option>` in a `<select>` list.

My jQuery is:

```
$('select#address_select_previous').click(function () {
    var previousAddress = $('select#address_select_previous option:selected').text();
    previousAddress = previousAddress.replace(/, /g, ', <br />'); 
    $('#previous_address_populated p').html(previousAddress);   
});
```

I originally had .change(function()) but I found out here, that IE 7 doesn't like that.

The problem is that the var `previousAddress` has no value (i.e. if I console log, or alert that value, it is null in IE7, but fine in other browsers), so it won't populate the div, as there is nothing to populate it with.

Comment: What exactly are you experiencing? Does the code posted not work? or are you asking why `.change` wasn't working, but this is? Please elaborate

Comment: @Jeremy B Sorry, I edited to explain the issue a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***-- EDIT --***

***[see working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/DceAP/)***

I also made some slight optimizations:

```
var $select = $('select#address_select_previous'),
    $populated = $('#previous_address_populated p');

$select.change(function() {
    $populated.html($select.val().replace(/, /g, ', <br />'));
}).change();
```

Comment: the find("option:selected") isn't even needed

Comment: This seems to just return the index of the object. If I click on the first option, the val = 0, second = 1 etc.

Comment: Go back to your fiddle and change val() to text(), you'll see it still works. val() is not the issue he is having. especially since you did not specify a val, add val attributes and it will break.

Comment: Thanks. This gets the value successfully, for some reason IE isn't wanting to populate a div using .html(). I will have a break and come back to it, thanks for the help!

Comment: I tested this solution in IE7 and it does populate the div correctly.

Comment: @Scott why yes it does, I had another bug somewhere else causing it to break. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
$('select#address_select_previous').val();
```

`.change()` should be working though...